# Custom Keyboard covers standard inputView

Tags: ios, keyboard, customization

I've created a custom inputView for the standard iOS keyboard and it works perfectly fine in both iOS 7 and 8.
But when using 3rd-party custom keyboard, it covers my created inputView. It shows the custom inputView for a second, and covers it with the custom keyboard view. I've tried several different custom keyboards, and they all have the same problem.

Is it possible to use inputView on any kind of keyboards? If possible, how to do it?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: I have also experienced the same problem, I hope someone can give the answer

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem and I found that using a view that is managed by a view controller will lead to this issue.
I made a simple demo to demostrate it:

As code shown below, `toggleInputView` will create a input view that work for both system keyboard and third party keyboard, while `toggleInputViewController` will only work for system keyboard.

```
import UIKit


class CustomInputViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var customInputViewController: CustomInputViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func toggleInputView(sender: AnyObject) {
        if textView.inputView == nil {
            textView.inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
        } else {
            textView.inputView = nil

        }
        self.textView.reloadInputViews()
    }

    @IBAction func toggleInputViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
        if textView.inputView == nil {
            if self.customInputViewController == nil {
                self.customInputViewController = CustomInputViewController()
            }
            self.textView.inputView = self.customInputViewController!.view
        } else {
            self.textView.inputView = nil
        }
        self.textView.reloadInputViews()
    }

}
```

As a result, you can build a input view by subclass `UIView` to resolve your problem.

Comment: The problem is that I need to use a controller, as I have several custom inputViews based on controllers to add different functionality into the application. All in all, the behaviour is strange and I will try to find some time to file a bug to Apple. Your code will help a lot, thank you!

Comment: Thank you @ainopara.It seems like an iOS bug instead. I needed to use a ViewController as well and came across the same problem, but adding my ViewController as a subview of an UIView did the trick. Thank you!